# mobile automation framework designing issue in javascript and node

Tags: javascript, frameworks, appium, ios-ui-automation, browserstack

While designing a framework for mobile testing, what segment of code to write for testing the element visibility and verifying a particular text. 
https://apkpure.com/bmi-bmr-calculator/com.prashantroid.bmibmr/download?from=details
this is the link for downloading the application.
please help in this matter.

Comment: Take a look at https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-check-if-a-certain-text-is-present-in-the-screen/11780

Comment: x path is fine. For css locator i am unable to find the proper command. sendKeys and setText works fine with browserstack. For running through appium only i am suffering